# First Person Virtual Reality Game Approaches in Unity

Tags: 3d, gps, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm trying to create a different kind of game. A geolocation (latitude,longtitude) will be used to put a 3d building model and mobile devices that is close to that area can login the game and walk around that 3d building on first person view.

Firstly, I try to convert geolocation to X,Y,Z cordinates by using the formula:

```
float earthRadius = 6378.137f;
float x = earthRadius * Mathf.Cos(lat)*Mathf.Cos(lon);
float y = earthRadius * Mathf.Cos(lat)*Mathf.Sin(lon);
float z = earthRadius * Mathf.Sin(lat);
```

Then, i try to find the differences between two (x,y,z) coordinates to realize 'how much  the player changed his/her location'

So, on every update on gps location, i changed players location.

There are many questions in my mind about that game (using compass and gyro to understand where player looks exactly, locating player and building based on gps etc.)

What could be the best approach for a game like this ? Is there a solution without using too much gps data. I mean, gps is not always precise enough. Can i make something like locating the building and the player via gps data at the beginning and using gyro-accelorometer-compass etc. to walk correctly on that building without taking gps data continuously.

Also I'm experiencing huge trouble about reflecting GPS locations to in-game x-y-z coordinates. For example, **Haversine Formula** can calculate the distance between the building and the player but i couldnt find a way to define relationship of their location. I mean a building can have a 10meters distance above the player or below ?  What can i do?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is not to ping for gps data every few seconds, because this KILLS battery life. Maybe every few min or so at the most.
Second, Shouldn't the building height match the player height? So I would assume 0 for height and just worry about x and y.
Third, You could also try to use the camera of the phone to set the height and use the distance from the ground to get the height of the player.